# Monad for Const?

Tags: haskell, monads

Why is there no monad instance for `Control.Applicative.Const`? Is following definition correct, or violates it the monad laws?

```
instance Monoid a => Monad (Const a) where
  return _ = Const mempty
  (Const x) >>= _ = Const x
```

And can you think of any useful application?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It violates the [left identity law](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws): `return x >>= f` must be the same as `f x`, but consider `f x = Const (x + 1)`.

Comment: Actually you have to use a monoid like `Sum`, but the observation is correct. And from your example it's clear that there is no way to fix the monad instance.

Comment: Reassuringly, the special case `Const ()` is a monad. Indeed, it's the terminal monad.

Answer (score 1):

ehird's answer explains what's wrong with the instance in the question. Here's a more in-depth explanation as to why there can be no other instance that works either, even if you were to choose constraints other than `Monoid`, unless the type has exactly one inhabitant (e.g., `()`). Any given type either has zero inhabitants, one inhabitant, or at least two inhabitants.

###### Case 1: zero inhabitants

You could write this total function, an obvious contradiction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
oops :: void
oops = case getConst (return () :: Const TheEmptyType ()) of {}
```

###### Case 2: one inhabitant

This special case actually is possible: it's isomorphic to `Proxy`. For completeness, here it is:

```
instance Monad (Const ()) where
    return _ = Const ()
    Const () >>= _ = Const ()
```

###### Case 3: at least two inhabitants

Let `x` and `y` be two different inhabitants of your chosen type. Write this helper function:

```
f False = Const x
f True = Const y
```

Now consider these two instantiations of the left identity law:

```
return False >>= f = f False
return True >>= f = f True
```

By parametricity, there's no way to implement `return` such that `return False` and `return True` are different, so you end up with the same value having to equal both `Const x` and `Const y`, which is a contradiction since we said earlier that `x` and `y` were different.

Comment: @dfeuer lowercase-v void was intentional there, so it will be a value of any type and not just the `Void` type, similar to how some functions take a `proxy t` instead of a `Proxy t`.

Comment: Oops...... Sorry about that.