# How to write this simple Monad?

Tags: haskell

I try to write this:

```
data A=A Int deriving Show

instance Monad A where
 return x=A x
 A x>>=f=f x

main=print a where a=A 1
```

I learn it from the book 《Learn You a Haskell for Great Good》：

```
instance Monad Maybe where
 return x = Just x
 Nothing >>= f = Nothing
 Just x >>= f = f x
 fail _ = Nothing
```

but got error:

```
a.hs:3:16: error:
? Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘A’ has kind ‘*’
? In the first argument of ‘Monad’, namely ‘A’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Monad A’
```

so how to write it? When finish, I can write

```
A 1>>\x->x+1
```

and get A 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make `A` an instance of `Monad` given its current definition.

The error message tells you that the compiler expects something of the kind `* -> *`. This means a type that takes a type as input, like `Maybe a`, `IO a`, or `[] a`. In other words, the type must be *parametrically polymorphic*.

In oder to get an intuitive sense of this, consider `return`, which has the type:

```
return :: a -> m a
```

The type argument `a` is unconstrained. This means that you should be able to take *any* value of type `a` and turn it into a value of the polymorphic type.

If I give you the Boolean value `False`, which `A` value will you construct from it? If I give you the string `"foo"`, which `A` value will you construct from it? If I give you the function `id`, which `A` value will you construct from it?

If you want to make your type a `Monad` instance, you must give it a type parameter, at least like this:

```
data A a = A Int deriving Show
```

Here, the `a` type parameter is in the phantom role; it's not used, but now you're at least able to make it a `Functor`. This version of `A` is isomorphic to the [Const functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Functor-Const.html). You can make it a `Functor` and `Applicative` instance, but [can you make it a `Monad`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530412/126014)